# Jquery wait and click more times

Tags: jquery, timeout, click, wait

I have a question because i don't understand this.

I want to wait between showing the next tab with jquery and coded something like this:

```
$('#tabs ul .ui-corner-top').each(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){},2000)
    $(this).children('a').click();
});
```

I've expected to see waiting for 2 sec if the next tab will be clicked.
But the Timeout is only starting once and all hrefs are immediate clicked without waiting.

Then I tried something different:

```
for (i=0;i<$('#tabs ul .ui-corner-top').size();i++) {
    setTimeout('changeTab(i)',i*3000);
}

function changeTab(i) {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout=setTimeout(function(){
        $('#mainContent').masonry();
    }, 1500);
    tablink='a[href*="#tabs-'+i+'"]';
    $(tablink).click();
}
```

The timeout is working here, but I don't know why. Here I only have the problem left with the immediate clicking. It is not waiting until clicking the next tab.

Can somebody Help?

thanks in advance

---

i totally wrote weird stuff.. sorry... this is my actual code and its working almost:

```
for (i=0;i<$('#tabs ul .ui-corner-top').size();i++) {
    tablink='a[href*="#tabs-'+i+'"]';
    setTimeout('changeTab(tablink)',i*3000);
}

function changeTab(tablink) {
    $(tablink).click();
}
```

But he is only clicking the third tab (#tabs-2) 3 times, not every tab once (1,2,3) like i want. For explaining it: I want to switch automatically between tabs (jquery ui tabs) with an interval of waiting until next click.

Comment: Could you rephrase what you're trying to accomplish? It's not cklear from your question. Also, you should pass a function, not a string, to `setTimeout()` and `setInterval()`.

Comment: See my edit, I think I've figured out what you are after. You need to actually pass the `tablink` variable to `changeTab`, right now it's just part of a string. Like I said before, **don't pass strings to `setTimeout`**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you are asking... you have a number of tabs that you want to progress through with a timer, however your query is being too greedy.

What you will want to do is take your collection invoke each of them with a different offset.

Cheaply, you could do something like this...

```
    var tabs = $(this).children('a');
    var numberOfTabs = tabs.length;
    for (var item = 0; item < numberOfTabs; item++)
    {
        window.setTimeout(function(){tabs[item].click();},2000*item);
    }
```

You must remember that JQuery returns an array of results that match your query, AND that timers are not sequentially initialized. A timer declaration starts counting down immediately when you define it. You've merely asked JQuery to start a timer for each result to be activated at the same time.

Comment: this seems to be very good but i get the error 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'click' of undefined'. in tabs i have this '[
<a href=​"#tabs-1">​1​</a>​
, 
<a href=​"#tabs-2">​2​</a>​
, 
<a href=​"#tabs-3">​3​</a>​
]'

Comment: When you access an element of a jQuery object by index, like `tabs[item]`, you get back the underlying DOM element, not a jQuery-wrapped DOM element. You'd have to do `$(tabs[item]).click()`.

Comment: do you know how this can be endless looped?? like repeating it from the first tab again... endless loop?

Comment: function doTabSlide(){
 $('#tabs ul .ui-corner-top').each(function (i)
 {
  setTimeout(function ()
  {
      $('a[href*="#tabs-'+(i+1)+'"]').click();
   if( (i+1)==$('#tabs ul .ui-corner-top').size() ){
    setTimeout(function (){doTabSlide()}, 300);
   }
  }, i*300);
 });
};
doTabSlide();